# cors error header disallowed by preflight response

Tags: php, cors

i am struggling with this error

```
         cors error header disallowed by preflight response
```

tried almost all possible combination but chrome is continuously throwing this error

i have tried these headers from php

```
   // header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: stylishgames.myshopify.com');
      header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');


 // header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
// header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS');
header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8');
// header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * ');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST, PUT');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
```

same thing can be checked live at this site

go to this page

```
   https://stylishgames.myshopify.com/products/test-product1
```

click on add to cart and then in bottom you can see campaign_page.php in network tab when you click on ADD to cart and then click next and this error will appear,

any help will be great

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I used this in brave and works fine for me.

He disable CORS in brave!

```
brave.exe --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security "http://localhost:8098/your_local_url"
```

Answer (score 12):

Explicitly allow headers required by the browser's request. Get the full list from the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` field of the preflight request.

### Explanation

The browser sends the *preflight request* to inquire whether the server hosting the cross-origin resource will permit the actual request. The preflight's `Access-Control-Request-Headers` field lists the headers the request will use. The server response contains the complementary `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` field, specifying the allowed headers (See [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS))

The `Header Disallowed By Preflight Response` error appeared because your server doesn't allow some of the headers from the browser's request. To see which ones are missing, look at the preflight request sent by Chrome. You can access it on the Network tab.

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` were irrelevant to the error — that's why changing them had no effect.

Comment: "To see which ones are missing" part kind of threw me off a bit. It's actually that you're sending headers that aren't being accepted so you have to either remove them or find a workaround so that they're accepted.